# What will happen to the non-sandboxed apps on the Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-app-store, sandbox

The Mac App Store sandbox deadline has finally arrived on June 1. What does this exactly mean for existing, non-sandboxed apps? I see existing apps in the Mac App Store that are *not sandboxed* and yet were updated just a few days ago, clearly after the deadline. One of the 
developer mails from Apple says:

> If you have an existing app on the Mac App Store that is not
>   sandboxed, you may still submit bug fix updates after June 1.

Does Apple say what constitutes a bugfix release? Is there also a deadline on this, or will the bugfix updates be accepted indefinitely? Will Apple eventually pull the non-sandboxed apps from the store, or can they survive indefinitely?

Comment: I'm confused. The deadline is July 1, the apps were updated a few days ago, but that was clearly after the deadline? I feel like I just fell into a wormhole.

Comment: `s/July/June/`, FatalError on my side :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

- The quote from the developer e-mail already states that bugfixes will be accepted for non-sandboxed apps. No idea about what constitutes a bugfix update, I guess it’s just anything apart from a new app release.
- There’s an official FAQ listed in the [sandbox resource center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/app-sandbox/). The FAQ states that apps that were in the store before June 1 will remain in the store even without adopting the sandbox.